# Differentiating the exponential map of a unitary group

Tags: differential-geometry

I consider a unitary group $U \in U(N)$ with an exponential map: $ U = \exp (iH)$, with $H$ hermitian. I am not sure if I can do the following calculation:

$U^\dagger d U = \exp (-iH) i dH \exp (iH) = i dH$

Thanks in advance for response.

Comment: Which part cannot you do?  Since the space $U(N)$ is finite dimensional, the Hermitian matrix $H$ is bounded.  Now you can manipulate $\exp(i H)$ just as if $H$ were a number.  The only difficulty that will enter is if you have another matrix $V = \exp(i L)$ - then the usual rules of algebra and calculus won't apply if $HL \ne LH$.  But with only one matrix, $H$, in the picture, you can define $\exp(iH)$ using power series, and manipulate it term by term.

Comment: Sorry - my opening remark was a bit rude.  But yes, you can do this.

Comment: My main objections was whether $[dH,H] =0$ holds, in order to do the kind of operations youre describing. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Actually, now I think about it, I was completely wrong.  I think you were correct to be concerned.